# How should I restore the level of sinking paver bricks in my driveway?

Tags: brick, driveway

My driveway is over thirty years old but hasn't had any maintenance work, so while it is mostly fine there are some issues. The one that concerns me most is the sinking of some of the bricks around the manhole at the end of the drive.

[image]

I haven't yet pulled them up in case things break, but am I right in thinking it should be a sand bed under the bricks and it has perhaps just washed away down past the metal walls of the manhole?

If that is the case, is the fix to pull the bricks up, lay sand to level and tamp bricks back down?

Comment: Pull bricks up, tamp crushed rock (coarse sand) to fill the voids, *then* pack and screed level sand, then tamp pavers back into place.

Comment: Jimmy, this sounds like an “answer”.  Suggest moving your comment to an answer!